# Multiple Dynamic Jquery Datepicker with separate min max date dependency

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

```
This Block Of Code is Under Loop ForEach

html += '<tr>';
    html +='<input type="hidden" name="amdomainpurchasetype[]" value="'+v.domainpurchasetypeid+'" />';

    html +='<td style="text-align:center;">';
        html +='<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group input-group">';
            html +='<span class="input-group-addon"><b>From</b></span>';
            html +='<input data-othervalue="' +v.domainto+ '" id="pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate' +v.id+ '" tabindex="3" required class="form-control input-lg pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate" name="actmanagerdomainformfromdate[]" value="'+v.domainfrom+'" type="text" readonly />';
        html +='</div>';
    html +='</td>';

    html +='<td style="text-align:center;">';
        html +='<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group input-group">';
            html +='<span class="input-group-addon"><b>To</b></span>';
            html +='<input data-othervalue="' +v.domainfrom+ '" id="pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate' +v.id+ '" tabindex="3" required class="form-control input-lg pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate" name="actmanagerdomainformtodate[]" value="'+v.domainto+'" type="text" readonly />';
        html +='</div>';
    html +='</td>';
html += '</tr>';
```

After **each iteration** html is rendered to div using **.html(html)**

After **.html(html)**

Loop continue following code for making **datepicker()**

```
// From date datepicker
$("#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate"+v.id).datepicker(
{
        changeMonth:true,
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate"+v.id).val(),
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate"+v.id).datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
    }
});

// To date datepicker
$("#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate"+v.id).datepicker(
{
    changeMonth:true,
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate"+v.id).val(),
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate"+v.id).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
    }
});
```

After **loop complete** it showing all fields

But only making **last input as datepicker** :( not every field which I required

**No error** on **console** showing

**All values coming are present, valid and checked**

****Dynamic ids can also be seen in html source**, but for example if 4 datepicker(2 from datepicker, 2 to datepicker) it only showing for last one**

Can anyone suggest what is the possible issue here?

**Example situation created on jsfiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/6akt0pe3/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current jquery code you are using `.html()` this will remove all previous htmls and add new htmls to your `dom` . So ,`html` variable has `tr` inside it but on each iteration you remove previous html and add new because of this `datepicker` doesn't find input which it need to initialize as on each iteration `v.id` value also gets changed .So , instead remove all `.html()` code and use `.append()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  data = [{
      id: 1,
      datefrom: "22-06-2021",
      dateto: "22-07-2021"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      datefrom: "15-07-2021",
      dateto: "15-08-2020"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      datefrom: "12-06-2021",
      dateto: "12-07-2021"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      datefrom: "17-06-2021",
      dateto: "17-07-2021"
    }
  ];
   $("#div").html("")
  $(data).each(function(i, v) {
  //use append..here
    $("#div").append(`<tr><td><input data-othervalue="${v.id}" id="pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate${v.id}" tabindex="3" required class="form-control input-lg pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate" name="actmanagerdomainformfromdate[]" value="${v.datefrom}" type="text" readonly /></td><td><input data-othervalue="${v.id}" id="pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate${v.id}" tabindex="3" required class="form-control input-lg pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate" name="actmanagerdomainformfromdate[]" value="${v.dateto}" type="text" readonly /></td></tr>`)
//then access inputs..
    $('#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate' + v.id).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      minDate: new Date(),
      maxDate: $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate" + v.id).val(),
      onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate" + v.id).datepicker("option", "minDate", selected);
      }
    });
    $('#pendingactmanagerdomainformtodate' + v.id).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      minDate: $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate" + v.id).val(),
      onSelect: function(selected) {
        $("#pendingactmanagerdomainformfromdate" + v.id).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="div">
</div>
```